Why is isospin utilized in determining the branching fraction of $K_1(1270)\to K\pi\pi$ final states?
The branching fraction of $\mathcal{B}_{K_1 \rightarrow K^{+} \pi^{+}\pi^{-}}$ is determined by $$\mathcal{B}_{K_1 \rightarrow K^{+} \pi^{+}\pi^{-}}=\frac{1}{3} \times \mathcal{B}_{K_1 \rightarrow K \rho}+\frac{4}{9} \times \mathcal{B}_{K_1 \rightarrow K^{\bullet}(892) \pi}+\frac{4}{9} \times 0.93 \times \mathcal{B}_{K_1 \rightarrow K_0^*(1430) \pi}. $$
Because the sum of branching fractions of $K_1\to K\rho/K^*\pi$ is 100%. So why the isospin is needed? The branching fractions in PDG have stands for the probability of $K_1$ decay.

Where does this come from? What are you asking?

Are you trying to resolve this?

Hi Cosmas. I am looking at the Ref[54] of this measurement. It measured the branching fraction of $D^0\to K^-\pi^-\pi^+e^+\nu_e$ first and then use Ref[54] to get the  branching fraction of $D^0\to K^1(1270)e^+\nu_e$. The key is the coefficients of the $K_1(1270)$ subdecays.

Perhaps you might ask @Roger Barlow of ref 53 who is active on this site. I might work out the iso-Clebsches in a hint answer...

I assume you are trying to appreciate the coefficients 1/3 and 4/3 out of the isospin Clebsches
$ |  \langle j_1 \, m_1 \, j_2 \, m_2 | J \, M \rangle|^2$
for essentially the two separate decay alternatives
$$
K_1(270)\to K\rho,\\
 K_1(270)\to K^*(892,1430)~\pi. 
$$
The $I(J^P)$ quantum numbers of the particles involved are,



meson
$I(J^P)$




$K_1$
1/2 ($1^+$)


$K$
1/2 ($0^-$)


$K^*$
1/2 ($0^+$)


ρ
1 ($1^-$)


π
1 ($0^-$)



so the second decay is a P-wave (antisymmetric), and the first S-wave (symmetric) by spin-parity. These decay products then decay to $K\pi\pi$, almost exclusively, which should not concern us for your purposes, as they  are basically exclusive, but for a little "dirt" for the 1430, dealt with in your previous question via this.
So the relative coefficients of the two decay modes should be the squares of these, but I have not seen the source of the extra factor of 2 in the coefficient of the P-wave-decay.
There must be something doubling up its states, which is not apparent to me (yet), but you might be able to catch counting all the strange states. In any case, 1/3+2/3=1.
